# how to pin location on google map on click the Location

Tags: android, google-maps, bitmap

i am trying google map first time i got a some tutorial from [From this site](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android#)

where we can pin a location but it does not show pin a particular location on click the code is given below

```
public class GoogleActivity extends MapActivity 
{    
    MapView mapView; 
    MapController mc;
    GeoPoint p;

class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
{


    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, 
    boolean shadow, long when) 
    {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

        //---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
        Point screenPts = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);

        //---add the marker---
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);            
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-50, null);         
        return true;
    }
} 

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    LinearLayout zoomLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.zoom);  
    View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls(); 



    zoomLayout.addView(zoomView, 
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
    mapView.displayZoomControls(true);

    mc = mapView.getController();
    String coordinates[] = {"1.352566007", "103.78921587"};
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

    p = new GeoPoint(
        (int) (lat * 1E6), 
        (int) (lng * 1E6));

    mc.animateTo(p);
    mc.setZoom(17); 
    mapView.invalidate();


     //---Add a location marker---
     MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
     List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
     listOfOverlays.clear();
     listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);        

     mapView.invalidate();
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

now what i need is that i want to pin a location when i chick a particular location. How can i implement a click event in google map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe MapOverlay class has an [onTap()](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/Overlay.html#onTap%28com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint,%20com.google.android.maps.MapView%29) method you can override. It will be called when you tab on the map and a GeoPoint object will be passed as a parameter describing the location that was taped.

Comment: can you please more specific?

Comment: You wanted to know how to react to a click on the map so you can draw a marker on the map at the position the user clicked? Correct? So you can override the onTab() method of you Overlay class. This method will be called when a user click or tab on the map.